# how to filter json values to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have a json file like this

```
let myfile = [
    {"name":"John","eid":664,"socialid":399,"testid":799},
    {"name":"Sam","testid":249,"eid":64,"socialid":80},
    {"name":"Albert","eid":422,"testid":20,"socialid":10},
    {"name":"Michel","eid":497,"testid":15,"socialid":60}]
```

from this above json I want to filter all values by it's key name and push it to an array.
expected output is:

```
"name": ["John", "Sam", "Albert", "Michel"],
"eid": [664, 64, 422, 497],
"testid": [799, 249, 20, 15],
"socialid": [399, 80, 10, 60]
```

How to make this happen ?

I tried like this

```
let arr3 = [];
$.each( myfile, function( key, value ) {
  if(this.hasOwnProperty('name'))
  {
    console.log("is there")
    arr3.push(value);
  }
});
console.log(arr3);
```

it's not working as expected.

Comment: @Meeravali What have you tried?

Comment: also, your desired output is ambiguous. You say you want an array, but this looks like an object (sort of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to accumulate value corresponding to each key in an object.

```js
let myfile = [{"name":"John","eid":664,"socialid":399,"testid":799}, {"name":"Sam","testid":249,"eid":64,"socialid":80}, {"name":"Albert","eid":422,"testid":20,"socialid":10}, {"name":"Michel","eid":497,"testid":15,"socialid":60}],
    result = myfile.reduce((r,o) => {
      Object.entries(o).forEach(([key,value]) => {
        r[key] = r[key] || [];
        r[key].push(value);
      });
      return r;
    },{});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the array into one object:

```js
let myfile = [
    { name: 'John', eid: 664, socialid: 399, testid: 799 },
    { name: 'Sam', testid: 249, eid: 64, socialid: 80 },
    { name: 'Albert', eid: 422, testid: 20, socialid: 10 },
    { name: 'Michel', eid: 497, testid: 15, socialid: 60 },
];

console.log(
    myfile.reduce(
        (result, item) =>
            Object.entries(item).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
                result[key] = result[key] || [];
                result[key].push(value);
                return result;
            }, result),
        {},
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You main problem is, you try to access `publication` which does not exist in the inner objects.

For an inline renaming, you could take an object with the given name as key and the new name as value and take the actual key as default value. Then create a new array, if not exists and push the value to it.

Finally, you get an object with wanted keys with all value from the given data.

```js
var myfile = [{ "name": "John", "eid": 664, "socialid": 399, "testid": 799 }, { "name": "Sam", "testid": 249, "eid": 64, "socialid": 80 }, { "name": "Albert", "eid": 422, "testid": 20, "socialid": 10 }, { "name": "Michel", "eid": 497, "testid": 15, "socialid": 60 }],
    replace = { name: 'publication' },
    result = myfile.reduce((r, o) => Object.entries(o).reduce((p, [k, v]) => {
        k = replace[k] || k;
        (p[k] = p[k] || []).push(v);        
        return p;
    }, r), Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
let json=[
    {"name":"John","eid":664,"socialid":399,"testid":799},
    {"name":"Sam","testid":249,"eid":64,"socialid":80},
    {"name":"Albert","eid":422,"testid":20,"socialid":10},
    {"name":"Michel","eid":497,"testid":15,"socialid":60}
]
let output={
  publication:[],
  eid:[],
  testid:[],
  socialid:[]
}
for(let i in json){
    output.publication.push(json[i].name)
    output.eid.push(json[i].eid)
    output.testid.push(json[i].testid)
    output.socialid.push(json[i].socialid)
}
console.log(output)
```

I hope that this will help you!

Comment: Why not `for(let i in json){` ?